# date format error while merging files using stata

Tags: stata

I'm completely new to **stata**. I'm trying to merge 3 different datasets which have dates in them with format *(d-mmm-yy)*. While trying to merge i'm encountering with an error saying

```
date is str 9 in using data stata
r(106)
```

I have no clue what this error is about. Need some help. I can provide any additional info if required.

Thanks

Comment: For each of your 3 datasets, what does -describe date- produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means that in some data sets, the date is stored as a number (Stata's format is Unix-like, # of elapsed days since 1 Jan 1960), while in others, it is a string (which is exactly what Stata tells you). You need to convert them all to the same format, e.g. with

```
generate long n_date = date(date, "DMY", 2050)
```

See `help date()` or `help date functions`.